# Selenium browser interference when using ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: multithreading, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler, python-multithreading

apologies if this code has become convoluted. I don't have much experience with threading and I've been throwing everything at the wall to see what sticks.

My goal is to run two parallel instances of a recursive, Selenium-based web crawler script. Each crawler runs a separate instance of ChromeDriver. The browsers each launch separately, but as they start crawling, each browser instance begins to crawl the other's links, switching back and forth throughout the duration.

I've tried adding locks at various points, but these don't seem to help. Ultimately I want each browser to run only one instance of a crawler and close the browser once complete. Is there a way that I can run these separately without cross-interference?

This problem doesn't occur when using multiprocessing, but using this causes other complications crawler class uses un-pickable objects such as an sqllite connector for logging purposes (or so that would seem to be the problem).

For additional context, I'm running these crawlers from a tkinter GUI which displays the current URL that each crawler is on as a status/progress indicator.

Any help or insight here would be much appreciated.

Crawler class:

```
class Crawler:
    def __init__(self, config, browser):
        self.config_path = config['path']
        self.name = config['name']
        self.startURIs = config['startURIs']
        self.URIs = config['URIs']
        self.maxDepth = config['maxDepth']
        self.new_content = 0
        self.regex_query = self.CreateURIPattern()
        self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.download_dir = config['download_dir']
        self.browser = browser


    def Crawl(self, URL, maxDepth, q):
            queue = Queue()
            lock = threading.Lock()

            print(self.config_path, URL, threading.currentThread().getName())
            
            lock.acquire()

            queue.put(URL)

            browser = self.browser

            q.put([self.config_path, URL])

            self.crawled_links.append(URL)

            self.browser.get(queue.get())

            raw_links = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
            
            for link in raw_links:
                href = link.get_attribute('href')
                
                if href is not None and href not in list(self.links.keys()):
                    if href.endswith('#') and link.get_attribute('onClick') is not None:
                        link = re.search(r'(?:https*:\/\/[\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+)[\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])',link.get_attribute('onClick'), re.X).group()
                    else:
                        link = href

                    if re.search(self.regex_query, link) is not None and re.search(r'.*#', link) is None:
                        self.links[link] = {'Referring URL': URL, 'Depth level': maxDepth - 1}


            for key, value in list(self.links.items()):
                if key not in self.crawled_links and value['Depth level'] > 0:
                    try:
                        self.Crawl(key, value['Depth level'], q)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                        pass
                else:
                    pass
            
            lock.release()
```

ThreadPool

```
class Runner():
    def __init__(self, config, browser):
        self.config = config
        self.browser = browser

    def run_crawler(self, browser, q):

        with open(self.config, 'rb') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            data['path'] = '/'.join(self.config.split('/')[-3:-1])

            time.sleep(3)

            try:
                c = Crawler(data, browser)

                for URI in c.startURIs: 
                    c.Crawl(URI, c.maxDepth, q)
                    done_message = (f'\nCRAWLING COMPLETE: {c.name}.\n{c.new_content} files added.\nCrawler took {self.timer(t1, time.time())}.\n')
                    print(done_message)
                    c.browser.quit()

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                try:
                    c.browser.quit()
                except:
                    pass
```

**EDIT:**
Sample Output displaying Class instance, chrome session ID, thread number, and URL. In the fourth row, you can see that thread 192084 has begun picking up links intended for Thread 192083 (Swiss Medical Weekly)

```
British Columbia Medical Journal <selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="237e27ff8e35528a0e1c24002d8b4bcb")> Thread-192084 https://bcmj.org/past-issues

British Columbia Medical Journal <selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="237e27ff8e35528a0e1c24002d8b4bcb")> Thread-192084 https://bcmj.org/cover/januaryfebruary-2022

Swiss Medical Weekly <selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="9f0b6f8e2ba9401da74629ef36284316")> Thread-192083 https://smw.ch/archive

British Columbia Medical Journal <selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="237e27ff8e35528a0e1c24002d8b4bcb")> Thread-192084 https://smw.ch/issue-1/edn/smw.2022.0910

Swiss Medical Weekly <selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="9f0b6f8e2ba9401da74629ef36284316")> Thread-192083 https://smw.ch/issue-1/edn/smw.2022.0708
```

Comment: not familiar with python but it doesn't look like each driver/browser has it's own thread here.  (you'll need a thread for each...)  So I think you need Crawler to initialize it's own driver, and then create a thread for each "c = Crawler(data)" class.  (Not all c, use different references....)  Then you'll need a sort of thread listener to coordinate the different drivers.  You might look into a non-recursive method that uses one thread instead.  (Using arrays to track visited URLs, end nodes, etc... though it does sound like a pretty complicated task...)

Comment: Thank you! I tried creating a separate thread for each class, but the problem still persists unfortunately

Comment: I think your problem is the recursion itself... these branches aren't really exclusive (like what you would have in a directory tree for instance...)  You're also going to end up with a  lot of loops in loops and way too many drivers/browsers running at once.  If you must use recursion, you might consider using something more light-weight such as HTMLUnit....  also make sure you keep track of visited URLs in another thread... that seems like it'd be the "controller" for all the other threads.  It would process thread notifications and take care of the data.

Comment: So you'd have a "listener" which takes the "notifications" (the threads will "notify" or call out to the listener, "hey I've got some results here, take them") from all threads and process accordingly...

Comment: I'm not sure that the problem is too many browsers running at once through recursion... the number of browser instances/threads remains limited to the number I specify, and each runs without any performance lags. I added some sample output above which can hopefully help clarify. The problem is that the crawlers begin loading each others links in the wrong browser/thread

Comment: In order for the recursion to work you need to use the number of threads the recursion needs.  You wouldn't know that ahead of time.  If you only have 2 that doesn't seem right at all for a recursive loop.  Also without something to manage the threads they won't know anything about what each thread has already crawled.

Comment: So you start a driver => Gather links => Start Thread 2, new driver/browser => Loop through links, 1st link opens a new thread=> Start Thread 3, new driver/browser =>... gather those links => ... etc... each array is fed back into the same method which gathers the elements of the array and that array is fed back in... that's recursion... but here each level of recursion need it's own threads driver/browser...